# Mongodb: Find a cada x dias

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

[Mongodb] Pessoal, estou com a seguinte situação:
Tenho vários documentos salvos com a seguinte estrutura:

```
{ ..., repetir : "semanal", a_cada: 2 }
```

Resumindo, tenho uma cron rodando diariamente e eu preciso buscar os documentos de acordo com a configuração de cada documento. No caso do documento acima, a query precisa retornar este documento a cada duas semanas. Sendo que tem casos em que o documento terá parâmetros diferentes, como ex.:

```
{ repetir : "diariamente", a_cada: 3 }
```

Pensei em criar uma data de início e a partir daí ir salvando as próximas datas de acordo com os parâmetros de cada documento. Mas isso não me parece legal...